# Complex Integration parametrisation

Tags: contour-integration, parametric, complex-integration

I'm trying to integrate $\int_\gamma (z^2-2)dz$ where $\gamma$ is a spiral that loops 3 times and ends at (3,0) on the Argand diagram.

I have found the parametric equations for this contour to be $\left(\frac{3}{2\pi}t\cos(3t),\frac{3}{2\pi}t\sin(3t)\right)$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$. How do I turn this into a suitable parametrization to integrate?

I considered setting $\gamma (t)=\left(\frac{3}{2\pi}t\cos(3t)\right) +i\left(\frac{3}{2\pi}t\sin(3t)\right)$, but I wasn't sure if this worked?

EDIT: Trying this with the exponential identity for my version of $\gamma=\frac{3e^{3it}t}{2\pi}$ I ended up with $\frac{-39}{8}$ which doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is homotopic to another, very simple path: the line segment between the endpoints.

Comment: So I just need to use the antiderivative of $(z^2-2)$? Then I get $\frac{1}{3}(8\pi^3)-2(2\pi)=\pi(\frac{8}{3}\pi^2-4)$ does this seem right?

Comment: @AccioHogwarts, the idea is right, but if I understand correctly your problem, the endpoints are $(0,0)$ and $(3,0)$.

Comment: Oh! Of course! So then $\frac{1}{3}(3^3)-2(3)=3$?

Comment: @AccioHogwarts, right.